# How get SID Placeholder in Limesurvey

Tags: limesurvey

problem.

Suppose I need to get SID of limesurvey of a single Survey to send via Mail.
This because I need to change url with single parameters to send via mail.

Just to reference, I mean this https://manual.limesurvey.org/Survey_participants#Email_placeholders

Anyway, I'm trying to get in someway something like {SID}.
I'm wondering, is possible?

Answer (score 0):

Totally possible. `{SID}` is the way to go.
Have you had trouble with it?